# Shortcut for Show potential fixes on OSX

Tags: macos, visual-studio

What is the Visual Code keyboard shortcut for `Show potential fixes` on Mac? This is what I mean:

[image]

The usual shortcut on Windows is to use `CTRL + .`. This is not applicable to OSX.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> works for me out of the box. (VS 2022)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but just wanted to point that the command is "Alt+Return"

Answer (score 0):

"Quick Actions". Shows up in VS for Mac. Default is Cmd+., but doesn't work from what I can tell. Swapped to Ctrl+.